# Selendroid not able to find elements in webview

Tags: webview, appium, selendroid

This may be strange question to ask. I am quite new to Mobile app testing. 
There are 2 hybrid apps.( One for Test purpose and one is deliverable app.) I am loading same URLs in WebView of both the apps. 
However, selendroid & appium are not able to locate elements loaded in deliverable app. But elements are getting located in test app.
Both apps are built with

```
API level 19 
SDK version 21
WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

What could be the problem.

Comment: Make sure webview is enable on your deliverable app.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue. Actually there were 2 WebViews in deliverable app. (WEBVIEW_1, WEBVIEW_0) I was switching to first(spinner view) and was trying to locate element which are actually present in WEBVIEW_0) . Thus, shifting to required webview solved the problem.